# How to get the substring between two markers in Python multiple times?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the following code:

```
s = '''alt="Thunder Force"/>ehkjehkljhiflealt="Godzilla vs. Kong"/>'''

for i in s:
    start = s.find('alt="') + len('alt="')
    end = s.find('"/>')
    substring = s[start:end]
    print(substring)
```

But it only prints out "Thunder Force" a lot of times. I would like that it finds "Thunder Force" and "Godzilla vs. Kong" and print those two once each. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex

```
import re
s = '''alt="Thunder Force"/>ehkjehkljhiflealt="Godzilla vs. Kong"/>'''
x = re.findall(r'alt="(.*?)"/>', s)
print(x)
```

output

```
['Thunder Force', 'Godzilla vs. Kong']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` and `re.findall()`

```
s = '''alt="Thunder Force"/>ehkjehkljhiflealt="Godzilla vs. Kong"/>'''

print(re.findall(r'(?<=alt\=").*?(?="/>)', s))
#['Thunder Force', 'Godzilla vs. Kong']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex solution that looks more like what I think you were trying to achieve with your posted attempt:

```py
start = 0
while True:
    start = s.find('alt="', start)
    if start == -1:
        break
    start += len('alt="')
    end = s.find('"/>', start)
    if end == -1:
        break
    substring = s[start:end]
    start = end
    print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^"]+` to match any char except `"` and repeat it 1+ times if you want to match at least a single character.

If an empty match is also ok, you can use `*` instead of `+`.

```
import re
s = '''alt="Thunder Force"/>ehkjehkljhiflealt="Godzilla vs. Kong"/>'''
x = re.findall(r'alt="([^"]+)"/>', s)
print(x)
```

Output

```
['Thunder Force', 'Godzilla vs. Kong']
```